# Keep getting error attribute is missing the android namspace prefix

Tags: java, android

Keep getting error attribute is missing the android namspace prefix

I RE EDITED THIS TO SHOW SOME OF THE CODE AS ITS DRIVING ME NUTS

iv edited and changed a few things and still cant work it iv tried adding the android pre fix to the line and nothing yet

re edited

```
`<games xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <games name="StarCraft"/>
        <games name="RomeTotalWar"/>
        <games name="Half Life"/>
        <games name="Half Life 2" />
        <games name="Sims" />
        <games name="Sims 2" />
        <games name="Sims 3" />
        <games name="Sim City" />

</games>`
```

I figured out the problem I just cant answer my own questions as of yet but it was simple to figure out after a time really solution is

```
<games xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <games android:name="StarCraft"/>
    <games android:name="RomeTotalWar"/>
    <games android:name="Half Life"/>
    <games android:name="Half Life 2" />
    <games android:name="Sims" />
    <games android:name="Sims 2" />
    <games android:name="Sims 3" />
    <games android:name="Sim City" />
```

Comment: Do you want to create a static array?

Comment: iv already made a parser and the array adapter for it as well ahh I think I see the problem in the R.java file as it wont let me add a public static to it as it just reverts its self back to its original state

Comment: So, the answer to my question is yes/no? If you please post the logcat and supporting code, maybe we can help better. ALl the best

Comment: There is over 7 files of code in which I dont want to put the entire lot here but that .xml file is the only one with the error

Comment: Sure, don't put the whole 7 files but logcat would help :). So, in your code you want to have a static array, With which you wish to fill in  the array adapter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by having the following in array.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<resources>
    <string-array name="games">
        <item>StarCraft</item>
        <item>Half Life</item>
        <item>CS</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

Then you can call it while creating a adapter, like this:

```
 private ArrayAdapter adapter2 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.doing, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
```

Since, I don't have the exact idea, where you want to use the adapter, you might need to adapt the code accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Either use string(s) instead of game(s) or if there is a games and game class existing in your code then supply complete package name before games.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the android namespace to the code itself solved the problem

```
<games android:name="StarCraft"/>
<games android:name="RomeTotalWar"/>
<games android:name="Half Life"/>
<games android:name="Half Life 2" />
<games android:name="Sims" />
<games android:name="Sims 2" />
<games android:name="Sims 3" />
<games android:name="Sim City" />
```